# Google Cloud SQL stuck at restart

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

My cloud sql instance is stuck in Restart sate for a very long time.
In the operations pane, the status of the Restart is showing as pending, and there was also an export happening whose state is still **Running** .

Is there an way i can force the restart or cancel the restart or recover the data from the regular backup ?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. If you pay Google for a premier account, you will be able to log a support ticket and they'll look into it and probably fix it.

There's not many options you have, maybe try restarting again?