# Google Cloud SQL Restart and Update

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Randomly, out of nowhere, we stopped being able to connect to the Google Cloud SQL database at almost precisely 8:30 am ET this morning.

We then tried to restart the instance and have been stuck for more than an hour with a similar situation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610481/google-cloud-sql-stuck-at-restart).  It seems that this sort of freak accident has happened before on Google Cloud SQL.

The problem is that the instance is completely unresponsive to any commands - either via the GUI or the command line.

To make matters worse, there's no way to call support unless you pay hundreds of dollars per month to join a plan.  I'm hoping that someone from Google might be trolling the SO threads with these tags, or someone who has dealt with this before can offer some advice.

Comment: 1st or 2nd generation? You can try the [Community Support](https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/list).

Answer (score 1):

Just providing update to this, for anyone who comes across the future...

The issue was with the Google Cloud SQL instance itself.  Someone from tech support had to go in at a lower level and restart the entire instance.  Basically, there's nothing you can do if you encounter the exact same situation.

This issue happened again just a few days ago (twice in the same 4 weeks), and again, there was nothing we could do.

**NOTE: When this happens, you CANNOT access your db backups.  This is serious cause for concern.**

This seems very strange for a hosted db product, and I've come across similar cases documented by others.

We're still waiting on a post mortem that has taken almost 2 weeks, despite our upgrading to "gold level support" for $400 per month.  In the meantime, we're migrating over to AWS as we've never experienced issues with downtown on RDS.