# Google CloudSQL instance update

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I've been running a google cloud sql instance for a while, and one day it suddenly started updating during a period outside of the maintenance window.

It just started printing " instance is being updated".

Has anyone else seen this issue? The db was completely unavailable during this period and I had no warning about it.

I've found this post [Google Cloud SQL Restart and Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660309/google-cloud-sql-restart-and-update)
but was wondering if anyone had any updates, as that post is a year or so old.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to regular maintenance (which is done during the maintenance window) there are some other occasions when your instance may go through this:

- You or another user on GCP changes instance size, flags, replication type, etc. You can check for this with the audit logs
- You are using the PostgreSQL beta and Google needs to restart the instance as part of the beta development. During beta no uptime SLA is provided.
- The machine hosting your instance has a hardware failure. Redundant storage and ACID storage engine means your data is safe in such a case, but MySQL must then be started on a new instance, resulting in a downtime period (esp if long crash recovery is needed).
- You hit a MySQL bug, which causes MySQL to crash and be restarted. You can check for this by looking at the MySQL logs to see if a crash is indicated.